# Apache not using mod_rewrite.c

Tags: php, apache, debian

So I just setup a linode server with debian, apache, etc. and now I'm trying to get an app that I'm developing running, but it requires `mod_rewrite.c`. So naturally, I went to the directory of the application (happens to be in PHP if that matters) and created a .htaccess with this inside of it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So they I headed over to my domain, `example.com/hello`, and it gave me a 404 error, when it should be showing me the content that index.php loads. Is there any reason why `mod_rewrite.c` wouldn't be working?

Comment: You could try removing the <IfModule> and </IfModule> lines, just to see if somehow Apache isn't identifying the module correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the module enabled in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled?